# SUM of columns from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

here is my data,

Table 1:

```
             STORAGE    HANDLING    TOTAL BILLING 
             -------------------------------------- 
                 1300    10900     
                    0    10950     
                     0    6000     
                     0    5950
```

Table 2:

```
 LINER REVENUE 
--------------- 
       1300 
        250 
       3000 
        200
```

I need to calculate Total Billing:

I tried with this code.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[FCLOverall] SET [Total Revenue] = SELECT SUM([STORAGE]),      SUM([HANDLING]), SUM([LINER Revenue])
FROM (SELECT [STORAGE], [HANDLING],[Container No]
       FROM [dbo].[FCLOverall]
      UNION ALL
     SELECT [Container No],[LINER Revenue]
       FROM [dbo].[FCL_Child])
```

It is throwing some error missing brackets and invalid keyword select. is the query is right or wrong?

Can someone guide a query how to calculate on this?

Comment: The UNION's two SELECT must have the same number of columns.

Comment: What jarlh said plus your SET cannot work as it stands, due to it returning 3 different columns. Try changing SELECT SUM([STORAGE]),      SUM([HANDLING]), SUM([LINER Revenue]) to SELECT SUM([STORAGE]) +      SUM([HANDLING]) + SUM([LINER Revenue])

Comment: Your data and your queries don't match.  For instance, columns are mentioned in the queries that are not in the sample data.

Comment: Instead of using union can I change to different expressions?

Comment: How Table1 and Table2 are joint? I mean, what line(s) of Table2 should be used to calculate the "total billing"?

Comment: UNION statement..

Answer (score 1):

does you find something below

```
 UPDATE [dbo].[FCLOverall]
    SET [Total Revenue] = 
   (SELECT SUM([STORAGE])+ SUM([HANDLING]) + SUM([LINER Revenue] ) as s
    FROM  (
        SELECT [Container No],[STORAGE], [HANDLING],0
           FROM [dbo].[FCLOverall]
          UNION ALL
         SELECT [Container No],0,0,[LINER Revenue]
           FROM [dbo].[FCL_Child]
             ) t )
```

Comment: Thanks zaynul, I throws same error at line 1 as invalid keyword 'select' and incorrect syntax near ')' in last line can I correct that. can I change to another expression or will it work?

Comment: Invalid column 'Liner revnue" it is showing and invalid syntax near t.

Comment: No column name was specified for column 4 of 't',  & Invalid column name 'LINER Revenue', both these error occurs. Thanks for helping

Comment: @krishna31 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7999babe967f462ddc57b8bacd2313eb this is the fiddle link here it is working fine

Comment: @krishna31 hello you have post again this as question but you have not given me feedback here and not even said why it not works for you cause it works fine in fiddle

Comment: Since I dont know why it is not working, I couldn't give feedback

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try based on the assumption that Container No is key field.

```
UPDATE U
SET U.[Total Revenue] = COALESCE(U.Storage,0) + COALESCE(U.Handling,0) + COALESCE(FCLC.[Liner Revenue],0)
FROM dbo.FCLOverall AS U
INNER JOIN dbo.FCL_Child AS FCLC
  ON U.[Container No] = FCLC.[Container No]
```

Comment: It was not throwing errors, but null are not handled in liner revenue it seems, many values in total revenue is throwing NULL. How can I handle it?

Comment: Any chance you can post the exact error (or most of it if it's huge) - thanks.

Comment: There was not error it was working, but some values are throwing null. Null are handled in the query itself i guess, but it is still giving null values in total revenue, dont know why

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE FO 
SET [FO.Total Revenue] = ISNULL(FO.[STORAGE], 0) + ISNULL(FO.[HANDLING], 0) + ISNULL(FC.[LINER Revenue],0)
    FROM [dbo].[FCLOverall] AS FO
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[FCL_Child] FC on FO.[FO.Container No] = FC.[Container No]
```