# Summing up of columns from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

here is my data,

Table 1:

```
         STORAGE    HANDLING    TOTAL BILLING 
         -------------------------------------- 
             1300    10900     
                0    10950     
                 0    6000     
                 0    5950
```

Table 2:

```
 LINER REVENUE 
--------------- 
   1300 
    250 
   3000 
    200
```

I need to calculate Total Billing:

Total Billing = Storage+Handling+Liner Revenue.

Can someone guide me a query for this.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7999babe967f462ddc57b8bacd2313eb have you checked this fiddle?

Comment: You should set An identifier and foreign key to link these data to each other then you can sum up them easily.

Comment: @Zaynul, I checked out that fiddle, but it was not working for me in sql server, i'm running out of ideas

Comment: what you tried show us so we can guide you

Comment: Here is another I tried,[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946599/sum-of-columns-from-different-tables],with union statement it is throwing error, with join statement NULL values are introduced(but null values are available in one of the columns)

Comment: @krishna31 does that fiddle output your expected output?

Comment: @krishna31 what does it mean not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SUM of columns from different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946599/sum-of-columns-from-different-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
SELECT h.Storage+h.Handling+j.[Liner Revenue] 
         From(SELECT 
               STORAGE
              ,HANDLING
              ,[TOTAL BILLING]
              ,ROW_NUMBER () over(order by rand()) as p
          FROM [Table 1] )h
          INNER JOIN 
          (SELECT 
               [LINER REVENUE]
              ,ROW_NUMBER () over(order by rand()) as p
          FROM [Table 2] )j
          on h.p=j.p
```

Comment: It is throwing error as "The multi-part identifier "p.Liner Revenue" could not be bound.
"

Comment: it's j I changed it

Comment: It is working,but while updating this total revenue,it is throwing error near first select. Following code I tried, update [dbo].[FCLOverall] set [Total Revenue] = 
SELECT (h.Storage+h.Handling+j.[Liner Revenue]) 
         From(SELECT 
               STORAGE
              ,HANDLING
              ,[Total Revenue]
              ,ROW_NUMBER () over(order by rand()) as p
          FROM [dbo].[FCLOverall] )h
          INNER JOIN 
          (SELECT 
               [LINER REVENUE]
              ,ROW_NUMBER () over(order by rand()) as p
          FROM dbo.FCL_Child )j
          on h.p=j.p

Comment: Even though this solution might be correct, it is not advisable to EVER do this. each row in the table should be identified and joined on the id's because row order can change.